# Cannot delete Files they just re-appear after deletion

Tags: delete

Hi to anyone who can help.

I am currently unable to delete files from my SharePoint document folder. I just need to delete some excel files but it's proving to be impossible. We have not had this issue before.

When I click delete either through web portal or file explorer the file disappears then after a few moments reappears. Just like it's a file permissions issue. I still get the alert e-mail to say it's been deleted. I am site admin and have always been able to delete files before with no problems.

One drive also keeps updating with no deletion of the file.

It's as if the whole SharePoint permissions has changed?

I can rename and move files to different folder locations but it always leaves the original in place.

Any ideas anybody. This is driving me NUTS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try modifying the file ? Are you able to modify it? If not then it might be some issue with file getting corrupted considering you have the appropiate permission. Also you can try removing the file from SharePoint Designer or from powershell. Below is the code to delete it using powershell. give a try:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http:// sharepoint-site-url ")
$web = $site.openweb()
$list=$web.Lists["Document-Library-Name "]
$listItems = $list.Items
$listItemsTotal = $listItems.Count
Write-Host $listItemsTotal
for ($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
  if($listItems[$x].name.Contains("file")) # file refers to the    name of the document
  {
    Write-Host("DELETED: " + $listItems[$x].name)
    $listItems[$x].Delete()
  }
}
```